# Trying to Tag random users in a discord server with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is my code, but no matter what I try it's only tagging the bot? Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I've spent hours on this and I've not been able to figure it out.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    user = random.choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} Youre the best')
```

I'm trying to get it to tag any random user.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you did not give the bot permission to receive users information (SERVER MEMBERS INTENT) on the site [Discord Developers](https://discord.com/developers) in the Privileged Gateway Intents section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

code is only mentioning the bot, which is executing the command!

Try this:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    members = [member for member in ctx.message.channel.guild.members if not member.bot]
    if not members:
        await ctx.send("There are no non-bot members in this guild.")
        return
    user = random.choice(members)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} You're the best')
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried this and I just get this error @Nova discord.ext.comm.ands.bot Ignoring Exception in command test?

Comment: It seems that the list members is empty! To avoid this error, you can add a check before the random.choice() call to make sure that the list is not empty. I've updated the code in the answer, can you try it now!

Answer (score 0):

As @DK404 has already mention, you probably didn't enable the Server Members Intent on [Discord Developers](https://discord.com/developers).

Also check if you have enabled the intent for your bot too. You can do that by adding the `intents` parameter to your bot instance:

```py
client = discord.Client(..., intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

After you do that try running the bot again.

By the way `ctx.message.channel.guild.members` is the same as `ctx.guild.members`